# Local Storage not fetching more than 6 item

Tags: javascript, local-storage, session-storage

I am working on a Resume builder website in django. what I wanted is when a user tries to edit prebuild resume template I want to store data in local storage. So that users stay on the page even after refresh. What I have done is created an object which is storing every value of HTML then I have set it to local storage.
but when I getItem then It is fetching only a max 5 elements after that when I change any content in the template it is storing into local storage but not fetching it. Please help me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>

        <title>Resume Template!</title>

        <style>

            .template

            {

                background-color:#fafdfc;

                height:650px;

                width:550px;

                border:3px solid blue;

                box-shadow:1px 1px 6px;

                padding:10px;

                float:left;

            }

            #temp

            {

                margin:35px 168px;

            }

            @media print{

            body *{

                visibility: hidden;     

                }

            .print-container, .print-container *{

                    visibility: visible;

            }

    }

    </style>

    </head>

   

    <body>

        <div id="temp" class = "print-container" >

            <div class="template" style="float:left; margin-right:15px;">

                <div style="float:left;padding:2px;" id="edit0" contenteditable="true" class = "save">

                   

                </div>

                <div>

                    <img src="images/resume%20pic.jpg" style="height:100px; width:100px; margin-left:56px; margin-right:20px; margin-top:8px">

                </div>

                <div style="float:none">

                    <p style="border-top:1px solid black;"></p>

                    <p style="font-size:12px; background-color:lightgrey; padding:3px" contenteditable="true">

                        <b id="edit1"  style="padding:3px;" class = "save">CAREER OBJECTIVE</b>

                    </p>

                    <p style="font-size:11px;padding:2px;" contenteditable="true" id="edit2" class ="save">To associate myself with a reputed organization where I can utilize my skills to fulfil the goals & objectives of the organization and could enhance my competencies and potential.</p>

                    <p style="font-size:12px; background-color:lightgrey; padding:3px">

                                        

                        <b contenteditable="true" id="edit3" style="padding:3px;" class = "save">EDUCATIONAL QUALIFICATION</b>

                    </p>

                    <table style="font-size:11px; border:1px solid black;padding:4px;" contenteditable="true" id="edit4" class = "save">

                        <tr>

                            <td><b id ='course'>Course</b>&emsp;</td>

                            <td><b id = 'Board'>Board/University&emsp;</b></td>

                            <td><b id = 'Clg-Name'>Name Of Institute&emsp;</b></td>

                            <td><b id  = 'yearofpassing'>Year Of Passing&emsp;&emsp;</b></td>

                            <td><b id = 'percentage'>Percentage/CGPA</b></td>

                        </tr>

                        <tr>

                        

                        </tr>

                    </table>

                    <p style="font-size:12px; background-color:lightgrey; padding:3px">

                        <b contenteditable="true" id="edit5" style="padding:3px;" class = "save">TECHNICAL SKILLS</b>

                    </p>

                    <ul style="font-size:11px; padding-left:15px;padding-bottom:2px;padding-right:2px;padding-top:2px;" contenteditable="true" id="edit6" class = "save">

                        <li id = 'tech-skill0'>Beginner of Jquery, Bootstrap, Nodejs, Reactjs, Express, Mongodb.</li>

                        <li id = 'tech-skill1'>Proficient in C, Python, HTML, CSS.</li>

                        <li id = 'tech-skill2'>Sufficient Knowledge of C++, SQL, Data Structure, DBMS, Javascript.</li>

                    </ul>

                    <p style="font-size:12px; background-color:lightgrey; padding:3px">

                        <b contenteditable="true" id="edit7" style="padding:3px;" class = "save">TRAININGS ATTENDED</b>

                    </p>

                    <ul style="font-size:11px; padding-left:15px;padding-bottom:2px;padding-right:2px;padding-top:2px;" contenteditable="true" id="edit8" class = "save">

                        <li id = 'training-attended0'>Attended 40 days training on "C++" at "WEBCOM Technologies, Yamunanagar" (June 2019 to July 2019).</li>

                        <li id = 'training-attended1'>Attended 21.5 hours training on "Python" from "Udemy" (July 2020 to Aug 2020).</li>

                    </ul>

                    <p style="font-size:12px; background-color:lightgrey; padding:3px">

                        <b contenteditable="true" style="padding:3px;" id="edit9" class = "save">ACADEMIC PROJECTS UNDERTAKEN</b>

                    </p>

                    <ul style="font-size:11px; padding-left:15px">

                        <li contenteditable="true" style="padding:2px;" id="edit10" class = "save">

                            <div style="float:left">

                                <b id = 'project-name0'>TRAVEL MANIA - </b>

                            </div>

                            <div style="font-style:italic; float:right; margin-right:40px" id = 'project-duration0'>(Duration - 2 months)</div>

                            <div style="float:none">

                                <br>

                                <p  id = 'project-description0'>(It is a travelling website that enables users to plan their travel without any hassle. It is a team project in which I worked as a front-end developer.)</p>

                            </div>

                            <br>

                            <br>

                        </li>

                    </ul>

                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="template">

                <ul style="font-size:11px; padding-left:15px">

                    <li id="edit11" contenteditable="true" style="padding:2px;" class = "save">

                        <div style="float:left">

                            <b id = 'project-name1'>JARVIS - PERSONAL ASSISTANT - </b>

                        </div>

                        <div style="font-style:italic; float:right; margin-right:48px" id = 'project-duration1'>(Duration - 1 week)</div>

                        <div style="float:none">

                            <br>

                            <p id = 'project-description1'>(This project assists the end-user with day to day activities like searching queries in Google, finding locations, sending emails, playing songs, searching instagram profiles, opening webcam and many more.)</p>

                        </div>

                        <br>

                    </li>

                    <li id="edit12" contenteditable="true" style="padding:2px;" class = "save">

                        <div style="float:left">

                            <b id = 'project-name2'>RESPRO - </b>

                        </div>

                        <div style="font-style:italic; float:right; margin-right:40px" id = 'project-duration2'>(Duration - 2 months)</div>

                        <div style="float:none">

                            <br>

                            <p id = 'project-description2'>(It is a website that provides a simple and efficient way of creating resume and cover letter for individuals. It is a team project in which I worked as a front-end developer.)</p>

                        </div>

                       

                    </li>

                </ul>

                <p style="font-size:12px; background-color:lightgrey; padding:3px">

                    <b id="edit13" contenteditable="true" style="padding:3px;" class = "save">SOFT SKILLS</b>

                </p>

                <ul style="font-size:11px; padding-left:15px;padding-bottom:2px;padding-right:2px;padding-top:2px;" contenteditable="true" id="edit14" class = "save">

                    <li id = 'softskill0'>Teamwork</li>

                    <li id = 'softskill1'>Leadership</li>

                    <li id = 'softskill2'>Communication skills</li>

                    <li id = 'softskill3'>Time management</li>

                </ul>

                <p style="font-size:12px; background-color:lightgrey; padding:3px">

                    <b contenteditable="true" id="edit15" style="padding:3px;" class = "save">ACHIEVEMENTS</b>

                </p>

                <ul style="font-size:11px; padding-left:15px;padding-bottom:2px;padding-right:2px;padding-top:2px;" contenteditable="true" id="edit16" class = "save">

                    <li id = 'Achievement0'>Won third position in FashP competition (2019).</li>

                    <li id = 'Achievement1'>Won first position in Flower Arrangement competition (2012).</li>

                    <li id = 'Achievement2'>Won second position in Drawing competition (2012).</li>

                    <li id = 'Achievement3'>Won certificate for best entry in group D of All India Camel Color Contest (2011).</li>

                    <li id = 'Achievement4'>Participated in Snacks Making competition (2011).</li>

                    <li id = 'Achievement5'>Participated in many Dance competitions.</li>

                </ul>

                <p style="font-size:12px; background-color:lightgrey; padding:3px">

                    <b contenteditable="true" id="edit17" style="padding:3px;" class = "save">PERSONAL PROFILE</b>

                </p>

                <p style="font-size:12px;padding:2px;" contenteditable="true" id="edit18" class = "save">

                   

                </p>

            </div>

        </div>

        <button id = "safe">Save</button>

        <input type="button" id = 'print' onclick = "window.print();" value = "print">

        <script src ="script.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

    </body>

</html>
```

Here Is my template I have deleted some private information.

My javaScript File :

```
window.stop();

document.getElementById("safe").addEventListener("click", function(){

var x = document.querySelectorAll(".save");

for(var i =0; i<x.length; i++)

{

    x[i].removeAttribute("contenteditable");

}

});

document.getElementById("temp").addEventListener("click", function(){

    var x = document.querySelectorAll(".save");

    for(var i = 0; i<x.length; i++){

        x[i].setAttribute('contenteditable', "true");

    }

});

const element = document.getElementById('temp');

if (typeof Storage !== 'undefined'){

    element.addEventListener("keypress", function(event){

        const myObject ={

            'name':   document.getElementById('name').innerText,

            'address': document.getElementById('address').innerText,

            'mobile':  document.getElementById('mobile').innerText,

            'e-mail':   document.getElementById('e-mail').innerText,

            'linkedin':  document.getElementById('linkedin-id').innerText,

            'career': document.getElementById('edit1').innerText,

            'text':   document.getElementById('edit2').innerText,

            'education': document.getElementById('edit3').innerText,

            'course': document.getElementById('course').innerText,

            'Board':  document.getElementById('Board').innerText,

            'Clg-name':  document.getElementById('Clg-Name').innerText,

            'yearofpassing':  document.getElementById('yearofpassing').innerText,

            'percentage':  document.getElementById('percentage').innerText,

            

            'class0' : document.getElementById('class0').innerText,

            'uni-name0':  document.getElementById('uni-name0').innerText,

            'college0':  document.getElementById('college0').innerText,

            'year0':  document.getElementById('year0').innerText,

            'percent0':  document.getElementById('percent0').innerText,

            

            'class1':  document.getElementById('class1').innerText,

            'uni-name1': document.getElementById('uni-name1').innerText,

            'college1': document.getElementById('college1').innerText,

            'year1': document.getElementById('year1').innerText,

            'percent1':  document.getElementById('percent1').innerText,

            

            'class2':  document.getElementById('class2').innerText,

            'uni-name2':  document.getElementById('uni-name2').innerText,

            'college2': document.getElementById('college2').innerText,

            'year2':  document.getElementById('year2').innerText,

            'percent2':  document.getElementById('percent2').innerText,

            'edit5':  document.getElementById('edit5').innerText,

            'tech-skill0':  document.getElementById('tech-skill0').innerText,

            'tech-skill1':  document.getElementById('tech-skill1').innerText,

            'tech-skill2':  document.getElementById('tech-skill2').innerText,

            'edit7':  document.getElementById('edit7').innerText,

            'training-attended0':  document.getElementById('training-attended0').innerText,

            'training-attended1':  document.getElementById('training-attended1').innerText,

            

            'edit9':  document.getElementById('edit9').innerText,

            'project-name0':  document.getElementById('project-name0').innerText,

            'project-duration0': document.getElementById('project-duration0').innerText,

            'project-description0': document.getElementById('project-description0').innerText,

            'project-name1':  document.getElementById('project-name1').innerText,

            'project-duration1': document.getElementById('project-duration1').innerText,

            'project-description1': document.getElementById('project-description1').innerText,

            'project-name2':  document.getElementById('project-name2').innerText,

            'project-duration2': document.getElementById('project-duration2').innerText,

            'project-description2': document.getElementById('project-description2').innerText,

             

            'edit13':  document.getElementById('edit13').innerText,

            'softskill0':  document.getElementById('softskill0').innerText,

            'softskill1':  document.getElementById('softskill1').innerText,

            'softskill2':    document.getElementById('softskill2').innerText,

            'softskill3':    document.getElementById('softskill3').innerText,

            'edit15':  document.getElementById('edit15').innerText,

            'Achievement0': document.getElementById('Achievement0').innerText,

            'Achievement1': document.getElementById('Achievement1').innerText,

            'Achievement2': document.getElementById('Achievement2').innerText,

            'Achievement3': document.getElementById('Achievement3').innerText,

            'Achievement4': document.getElementById('Achievement4').innerText,

            'Achievement5':  document.getElementById('Achievement5').innerText,

            'edit17':  document.getElementById('edit17').innerText,

            'father':  document.getElementById('father').innerText,

            'father-Name': document.getElementById('father-Name').innerText,

            'mother': document.getElementById('mother').innerText,

            'mother-Name': document.getElementById('mother-Name').innerText,

            'dof': document.getElementById('dof').innerText,

            'date': document.getElementById('date').innerText,

            'martial-status': document.getElementById('martial-status').innerText,

            'status': document.getElementById('status').innerText,

            'hobbies': document.getElementById('hobbies').innerText,

            'hobby': document.getElementById('hobby').innerText,

        };  

        localStorage.setItem("Content",JSON.stringify(myObject));

    })

}

const mysessionData =  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Content"));

document.getElementById('edit1').innerText = mysessionData.career

document.getElementById('edit2').innerText = mysessionData.text

document.getElementById('edit3').innerText = mysessionData.education

document.getElementById('course').innerText = mysessionData.course

document.getElementById('Board').innerText = mysessionData.Board

document.getElementById('Clg-name').innerText = mysessionData.Clg-Name

document.getElementById('yearofpassing').innerText = mysessionData.yearofpassing

document.getElementById('percentage').innerText = mysessionData.percentage

document.getElementById('class0').innerText = mysessionData.class0

document.getElementById('uni-name0').innerText = mysessionData.uni-name0

document.getElementById('college0').innerText = mysessionData.college

document.getElementById('year0').innerText = mysessionData.year0

document.getElementById('percent0').innerText = mysessionData.percent0

document.getElementById('class1').innerText = mysessionData.class1

document.getElementById('uni-name1').innerText = mysessionData.uni-name1

document.getElementById('college1').innerText = mysessionData.college1

document.getElementById('year1').innerText = mysessionData.year1

document.getElementById('percent1').innerText = mysessionData.percent1

document.getElementById('class2').innerText = mysessionData.class2

document.getElementById('uni-name2').innerText = mysessionData.uni-name2

document.getElementById('college2').innerText = mysessionData.college2

document.getElementById('year2').innerText = mysessionData.year2

document.getElementById('percent2').innerText = mysessionData.percent2

document.getElementById('edit5').innerText = mysessionData.edit5

document.getElementById('tech-skill0').innerText = mysessionData.tech-skill0

document.getElementById('tech-skill1').innerText = mysessionData.tech-skill1

document.getElementById('tech-skill2').innerText = mysessionData.tech-skill2

document.getElementById('edit7').innerText = mysessionData.edit7

document.getElementById('training-attended0').innerText = mysessionData.training-attended0

document.getElementById('training-attended1').innerText = mysessionData.training-attended1

document.getElementById('edit9').innerText = mysessionData.edit9

document.getElementById('project-name0').innerText = mysessionData.project-name0

document.getElementById('project-duration0').innerText = mysessionData.project-duration0

document.getElementById('project-description0').innerText = mysessionData.project-description0

document.getElementById('project-name1').innerText = mysessionData.project-name1

document.getElementById('project-duration1').innerText = mysessionData.project-duration1

document.getElementById('project-description1').innerText = mysessionData.project-description1

document.getElementById('project-name2').innerText = mysessionData.project-name2

document.getElementById('project-duration2').innerText = mysessionData.project-duration2

document.getElementById('project-description2').innerText = mysessionData.project-description2

document.getElementById('edit13').innerText = mysessionData.edit13

document.getElementById('softskill0').innerText = mysessionData.softskill0

document.getElementById('softskill1').innerText = mysessionData.softskill1

document.getElementById('softskill2').innerText = mysessionData.softskill2

document.getElementById('softskill3').innerText = mysessionData.softskill3

document.getElementById('edit15').innerText = mysessionData.edit15

document.getElementById('Achievement0').innerText = mysessionData.Achievement0

document.getElementById('Achievement1').innerText = mysessionData.Achievement1

document.getElementById('Achievement2').innerText = mysessionData.Achievement2

document.getElementById('Achievement3').innerText = mysessionData.Achievement3

document.getElementById('Achievement4').innerText = mysessionData.Achievement4

document.getElementById('Achievement5').innerText = mysessionData.Achievement5

document.getElementById('edit17').innerText = mysessionData.edit17

document.getElementById('father').innerText = mysessionData.father

document.getElementById('father-name').innerText = mysessionData.father-Name

document.getElementById('mother').innerText = mysessionData.mother

document.getElementById('mother-name').innerText = mysessionData.mother-Name

document.getElementById('dof').innerText = mysessionData.dof

document.getElementById('date').innerText = mysessionData.date

document.getElementById('martial-status').innerText = mysessionData.martial-status

document.getElementById('status').innerText = mysessionData.status

document.getElementById('hobbies').innerText = mysessionData.hobbies

document.getElementById('hobby').innerText = mysessionData.hobby
```

I know I have written very weird javascript but please Help me.

Or suggest some other way to do the same thing. I don’t know much I am just a beginner in web development.

Comment: First hit Ctrl+Shift+I, and check the Application Tab for Local storage. Are you saving all the values there or is it just the 5?

Comment: Also try console.log(myObject) and console.log(JSON.stringify(myObject)) right before you do setItem, to make sure your object is correctly transformed to JSON...

Comment: @Tushar Shahi Yes Checked it their also it storing the whole object into local storage just when it tried to edit after 5 items it stops show that item in template

Comment: @FrançoisHuppé Yes, I assured that it is making objects in the very correct way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not read properties containing hyphens in the property name like this :

'-', '+', '*' etc. are operands. You can understand why they will not work.

```
document.getElementById('Clg-name').innerText = mysessionData.Clg-Name
```

Try this :

```
document.getElementById('Clg-name').innerText = mysessionData['Clg-Name'];
```

Comment: Please mark this as the correct answer if this helps you.

Comment: Yeah! It Worked Thank you so much for your time. If it please I want to ask one more thing that when I click on the refresh button its shows the first previous content for fraction of seconds then local storage content. I wanted it to stop to show only edited content without showing previous content. Can you help me with this

Comment: Your function might be slow. Put one loader, set it to true in the very beginning. Set its display to false when the last line of your function is executed. Beware, this is only a simple solution. There might be a case that your loader is running forever because your inner code which uses storage never has an error. You might wanna handle that too depending on your scope of the app.